# How to pass Multiple Parameters through URL to Controller using Input::get('paramter1') in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route.php

```
Route::get('test/{paramter1}/{paramter2}', 'Somecontroller@somemethod');
```

In Somecontroller.php , I want these parameter like

`$val_1 = Input::get('paramter1'); $val_2 = Input::get('paramter2');`

and then $val_1 , $val_2 are passed to database.

How can I do that?

I have tried using the same. but it's not working.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

You just have them as arguments for the someMethod.

```
public function someMethod(Request $request, $paramter1, $paramter2)
{
    // Your code here...
}
```

Laravel will do the rest. It's detailed in the Laravel documentation under [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#basic-controllers).

Comment: function's arguments should be named the same as in the route definition

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo yes, they should, I've updated that.

Comment: `public function someMethod(Request $request , $parameter1 , $parameter2)
    {
        $val_1 = Input::get('paramter1');
        $val_2 = Input::get('parameter2');
        $users = DB::table('users')->insert(array(
            'id' => $val_1,
            'name' => $val_2,
        ));`
This is my code. I want my parameters value should be taken in Input::get format.

Comment: @Styphon can't i take them in Input:get format? if no then how can i do so?

Comment: No, because they aren't get variables. Why do you need to use `Input::get`? What is wrong with having them as arguments in your method? If you want to use `Input::get` then you would have to pass them as get variables, e.g. `http://localhost:8000/test?parameter1=1&parameter2=2`

Answer (score 2):

Try this below.

```
Route::get('{x}/{y}', 'PagesController@index');

public function index($x, $y)
{


}
```

Comment: `public function someMethod(Request $request , $parameter1 , $parameter2)
    {
        $val_1 = Input::get('paramter1');
        $val_2 = Input::get('parameter2');
        $users = DB::table('users')->insert(array(
            'id' => $val_1,
            'name' => $val_2,
        ));`
This is my code. I want my parameters value should be taken in Input::get format.

Comment: @BhavinShah you can use something like this $val_1 = $request->input('paramter1');

Comment: I have tried too, but didn't work. thanks for your help.